# How to retrieve a value from Firebase DB with Admin- TS

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the user's scores saved on my realtime DB. I use Cloud Functions- typescript .

```
//MY DB:    
"users": {
    "Michael": {
                 "scores": "1000"
               }
          }
```

My code on the Admin side (cloud functions)

```
exports.gettingValueFromDB = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => 
{

if (context.auth!==null)
{ 
const uid = context.auth.uid;
const ref =  admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/`);

//???
//const scores= ????   
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize:

```
var db = admin.database();
var uid = 'Michael';    
var usersRef = db.ref(`users/${uid}`);
```

Query once:

```
usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val.scores);
});
```

Asynchronous listener:

```
usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val.scores);
});
```

Reference: [Retrieving data from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)